# r markdown code and result do not show together

Tags: r, r-markdown

[image]

[image]

Could anyone help me figure out this problem? Why my code and result do not show in the same block? It is so weird. When I knit to HTML, it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `results="hold"` in your chunk. Here is a reproducible example using the `iris` dataset:

````
---
title: "Test"
date: "2023-01-28"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, results="hold"}
ncol(iris)
nrow(iris)
names(iris)
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: I tried it. But now the whole trunk of nrow,ncol,names move to the front of my text, which is  (a) Briefly describe .......

Comment: Hi @Vivien, you could use  ‘collapse =TRUE’ instead?

Comment: It doesn't work. They still show in front of the text.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible code in your question?

Comment: Sure. I added to my question.